# nodeJS how to use router to add icon tag into pug file?

Tags: node.js, pug, weather-api

Hello I think it's easier to show partial lines of my code. 
What I'm trying to do is when I input a zipcode, the right icon will show.
I'm using https://erikflowers.github.io/weather-icons/ this git. 
for example: if NY weather condition says clear
weather condition in weather.pug should be like `i.wi.wi-night-sleet`
is it possible to add class name in icon tag from topic.js? 
 or 
can I use equal statement in pug flie like  `- if text=='clear' i.wi.wi-night-sleet`

topic.js

```
    router.post('/weather', function(req,res){
  let url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=${req.body.zipcode}&units=imperial&appid=${apiKey}`
  request(url, function (err, response, body) {
     if(err){
       res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
       console.log('error: ' ,err);

     } else {
       if(req.body.zipcode.length != 5) {
         res.render('topic/weather', {text: "Zipcode does not exist"})
       } else {
         let weather = JSON.parse(body)
         let temp = weather.main.temp
         let location = weather.name;
         let day_weather = weather.weather[0].main;
         let message = `It's ${weather.main.temp} degrees in ${weather.name}!`;



//below this I want to call icon tag that has a class name
              res.render('topic/weather', {text: location + " : " + day_weather, weatherCondition: `i.wi.wi-night-sleet`});

       }
     }

   });

})
```

weather.pug

```
extends ./homepage
block navigate
  div.container-fluid
    div.row.row-centered
      p= text
        //- space 넣을떄
        = "  "
        if text
          = date


      div.col-lg-6.col-centered
        form.form-group(action='/weather', method='post')
          p    
            input(type='text', class="form-control", id="zipcode",name='zipcode', placeholder='zipcode')
          p
            button(type='submit', class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style='margin-right: 10px;') Login
```

Answer (score 1):

In your route just pass the identifying part of the icon you need:

```
res.render('topic/weather', {text: location + " : " + day_weather, weatherCondition: "night-sleet"});
```

Then here's what your pug template needs to look like:

```
i.wi(class= 'wi-' + weatherCondition)
```

or

```
i(class= 'wi wi-' + weatherCondition)
```

Either of those lines of pug will produce the same html:

```
<i class="wi wi-night-sleet"></i>
```